# Brackets in conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

When I work with a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
    'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
```

Why does the following statement throw an error:

```
df['one'] > 1 & df['two'] > 2
```

and this doesn't:

```
(df['one'] > 1) & (df['two'] > 2)
```

Or to be more precise, why do I need brackets here?

Comment: `&` is a bit operation for AND, so the second statement is evaluating 2 conditions and AND them (0 and 1)

Comment: `&`  has a higher precedence so `1 & df['two']` is evaluated first - which throws the error.